# Converting historic map data (raster) into polygon format?

Tags: polygon, convert, arcgis-pro, vectorization, historical-imagery

**How do I convert historical buildings from map data (raster) into a polygon format?**

The historic maps that I am referencing are the Sanborn Fire Insurance Maps. Here is the link to an example in case the image doesn't load:
https://www.loc.gov/item/sanborn01615_001/

[image: Sanborn Fire Insurance Map of Idaho City]

I want to preserve the outline of the buildings and turn those into polygons. Doing this manually is out of the question, as there are 300+ maps that need conversion. I have searched for many hours, but have not been able to find a good answer to this question.

I need to do this in ArcGIS Pro. I have tried to use the convert Raster to Polygon tool and then ran the Eliminate tool, hoping to combine sliver polygons into the actual features that I want.

**How do I convert historical buildings from map data (raster) into a polygon format?**

Comment: Using what GIS software?

Comment: Either ArcGIS Pro or QGIS

Comment: Please decide which of ArcGIS Pro and QGIS you wish to ask about in this particular question. That way you can tell us precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: please add, if you know, the projection/datum of the raster image.

Comment: @Mapperz Sanborn maps are very large scale; basically a local plane grid.